# Looping future events only in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, loops

Im trying to make an array with posts that all have a meta value called dato_start. I'm trying to only output post that have a date AFTER today

dato_start outputs 20161010 20:30 if the post is set to 10th october 2016 at 20:30.

I tried limiting it to only show date without time, but i stil can't seem to make it work. right now it just displays random posts. older than today as well as future dates.

```
    global $post;
$test = substr(get_field('dato_start'), 0, -6);
$today = date("Ymd", strtotime('today'));
echo $today;
    $args = array( 
        'post_type' => 'events',
        'order' => 'ASC',
        'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
        'meta_key' => $test,
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'meta_query' => array(
            array(
                'value' => $today,
                'compare' => '>=',
                'type' => 'DATE'
                )
            )
             );

$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
ob_start();
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
$eventitems = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'dato_start', false); 
 foreach ( $eventitems as $eventitem) :

echo 'my markup';

endforeach; 
endwhile;
return ob_get_clean();
}
```

Can someone spot where this is going wrong??

Comment: I spot at least a couple of issues here. First of all, `meta_key` is supposed to be the field name you want to order by if you are ordering by meta field. In your case: `dato_start`. Second: in meta queries, type `DATE` works with the 'compare' value BETWEEN only if the date is stored at the format YYYY-MM-DD and tested with this format. (see [docs](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Meta_Query#Usage)). So... either you give your `dato_start` this format, or (if you need Time information) you better use timestamp values in your field. It'll work both for filtering and ordering.

Comment: yeah i kept adding stuff while trying to get it to work, so its full of unnecessary variables.
Due to time pressure i decided to make an if statement in the foreach() checking if $test is a larger number than $today whilst making the query taking all post sorting from 'dato_start'.

I will have to do some research on this later on but thanks for taking a look.

Comment: Well, I wasn't talking about unnecessary variables. I meant `'meta_key' => $test` is wrong for your current `$test` value. Also, your `meta_query` won't work because your `$today` variable format isn't valid for meta_query comparison (it should be YYYY-MM-DD) and because you missed the key `key`. See [code examples](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Meta_Query#Initializing_WP_Meta_Query).

Answer (score 0):

Thinking of deadlines i decided to just make my $args loop through all event posts, while sorting by dato_start. I then made an if statement checking if $test was a larger number og equal to $today.

I realize this is probably a really inefficient and stupid way to do it, but it did the trick non the less.